# What is wrong with this javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window with a textfield that copies what you write into multiple text boxes, here is what i have to be inserted into the `<body>`.  When I copy my code into my perl file, everything after this colored as it's included in the html as if my flags are messed up.

```
<span class=DefMenuText>(click on "input" to open the new window)</span>
<form name=form>
<span class=PreText>externalID:</span>
    <input type=text name=externalID size=12>
    <span class=BodyText>[<a href="javascript:fill(
        'External ID',
        'opener.document.form.external_id.value',
        '<font face=Verdana size=2>' +
    'test' );"
    >input</a>]</span>

<br>
<span class=PreText>Cage:</span>
    <input type=text name=password size=10>
    <span class=BodyText>[<a href="javascript:fill(
        'cage',
        'opener.document.form.cage.value',
        '<font face=Verdana size=2>' +
    'test1');"
    >input</a>]</span>

<br>
<span class=PreText>Born:</span>
    <input type=text name=password size=10>
   <span class=BodyText>[<a href="javascript:fill(
        'born',
        'opener.document.form.born.value',
        '<font face=Verdana size=2>' +
    'test2' );"
    >input</a>]</span>

<br>
<span class=PreText>Comment:</span>
    <input type=text name=password size=10>
    <span class=BodyText>[<a href="javascript:fill(
        'comment',
        'opener.document.form.comment.value',
        '<font face=Verdana size=2>' +
    'test3' );"
    >input</a>]</span>

    </form>
```

Here is the javascript function, it uses $mouse which counter variable in the perl script to  count how many cages are available for mice to be used, and I'm using it as a counter to see how many fields need to be filled at any given time.

```
function fill( name, output, msg ) {
    newwin = window.open( '', '', 'top=80,left=60,width=350,height=200' );
    if ( !newwin.opener ) newwin.opener = self;
    newwin.opener.document.bgColor = "EBEBEB";
        with ( newwin.document ) {
        open();
        write( '<body onLoad="document.form.box.focus()">' );
    write( '<form name=form ' );
        write( '    onSubmit=opener.document.bgColor="EAE8E4";window.close()>' );
        write( msg );
        write( '<br>' );
        write( '<font face=Verdana size=2>' );
        write( '<p>You may enter your ' + name + ' here ' );
        write( '<center>' + name + ':' );
        write( '</font>' );
        for (int i = 1; i <= $mouse; i++)
        {
            write( '<input type=text name=box size=10 onKeyUp=' + output + '_' + i + '=this.value>' );
        }
        write( ' ' );
        write( '<input type=submit value="Finish">' );
        write( '</center></form>' );
        close();

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This code is making me emotional.

Comment: The font tag makes me cringe.

Comment: The unquoted attributes gets me.

Comment: One of these things is not like the other one of these things just doesn't belong

Comment: Seriously, stop using the `<font>` tag now, before you kill any more kittens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `int i = 1` to `var i = 1` (using Firebug got this in no time...)
See fixed version in: http://jsfiddle.net/Vur4H/

Also - see comments to your question regarding better choice of HTML tags and HTML in general :-)

Comment: Thank you for that, however when I click the [input] on the page body, no text field comes up in the window.  Sorry, I rarely ever work with javascript

Comment: You should look at what value you set to $mouse (check the source of the page in the browser). If I replace $mouse with 1 it works fine...